# How do I change the name of a shape key in an object to an if statement?

Tags: python, scripting, shape-keys

**1.**

I want change name of object's **shape key?**

So, I am currently using the following two scripts as buttons.

*First Code*

```
import bpy

bpy.data.shape_keys["Key_AType"].name = "Key_AType_RE"
bpy.data.shape_keys["Key_BType"].name = "Key_AType"
```

*Second Code*

```
import bpy

bpy.data.shape_keys["Key_AType"].name = "Key_BType"
bpy.data.shape_keys["Key_AType_RE"].name = "Key_AType"
```

[image]

The problem occurs when you accidentally press the same command twice.

So sometimes i make a mistake of clicking
[image]

So I thought, I want to change the First Code to the following if statement.

**If mesh named "Cube" has  shape_keys named "key_AType", then run the command**

The following script doesn't work.
I just want to complete it in a similar format, but I'm not sure.

```
import bpy
sh=bpy.data.objects['Cube_AType']
for shape in sh.obj.data.shape_keys:
    if (shape.name=='Key_AType'):
        bpy.data.shape_keys["Key_AType"].name = "Key_AType_RE"
        bpy.data.shape_keys["Key_BType"].name = "Key_AType"
```

Comment: If your code fragment didn't get mangled by my browser your problem is that the last two lines need to be indented one more time each.  Instead of being directly under the 'i' in 'if', the 'b' in each line should be under the 's' in 'shape'

Comment: The indentation has been corrected in the post as given in your answer.
Other issues remain, but thanks for pointing out the indentation part.

Comment: Issues with last part of code i) no idea what you are attempting to iterate over?  The ID object is `context.object.data.shape_keys` _ie_ it belongs to the mesh not the object  ii)  if iterating over all shape keys (`bpy.data.shape_keys`)  it matters what order the keys are in.  If  there is a shape key set named "Key_AType" to begin with, the if will be true once if b is before a and twice otherwise.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Naming convention.**

Each object of an ID type has a unique name. (Unless it is linked from another file, let's consider it's not.)  Shape keys are an ID object `bpy.data.shape_keys`

Trying to assign a name that already exists appends `.nnn` to the name starting from `001`

To get around this, swap the names in one method. Here is a method to do this, a is assigned b's name which exists, so a number is appended, b gets a's name. Assign the saved value of b's name to a.

```
def swapnames(a, b):
    name = b.name
    a.name, b.name = b.name, a.name
    # naming convention will set count on a's name, fix
    a.name = name

>>> ska
bpy.data.shape_keys['A']

>>> skb
bpy.data.shape_keys['B']

>>> swapnames(ska, skb)
>>> ska, skb
(bpy.data.shape_keys['B'], bpy.data.shape_keys['A'])

>>> swapnames(skb, ska)
>>> ska, skb
(bpy.data.shape_keys['A'], bpy.data.shape_keys['B'])
```

Shape keys belong to the mesh, or data part of a mesh object, hence if shapekey "A" is on mesh of object "Cube", and "B" on object "Cube.001"

```
>>> D.objects['Cube'].data.shape_keys
bpy.data.shape_keys['A']

>>> swapnames(D.objects['Cube'].data.shape_keys, D.objects['Cube.001'].data.shape_keys)
>>> D.objects['Cube'].data.shape_keys
bpy.data.shape_keys['B']
```

**Text Editor Script Examples**

Select exactly 2 mesh objects, swaps shape keys' names

```
import bpy

context = bpy.context

def swapnames(a, b):
    name = b.name
    a.name, b.name = b.name, a.name
    # naming convention will set count on a's name, fix
    a.name = name


sks = [o.data.shape_keys for o in context.selected_objects if o.type == 'MESH']

if len(obs) == 2:  # "psuedo poll"
    swapnames(*sks)  # same as swapnames(sks[0], sks[1])
else:
    print("Select exactly 2 mesh objects")
```

Will do same for other ID objects *eg* blender objects, this will swap the name of the objects.

```
# swap object names

obs = [o for o in context.selected_objects if o.type == 'MESH']
if len(obs) == 2:  # "psuedo poll"
    swapnames(*obs)
else:
    print("Select exactly 2 mesh objects")
```

the meshes

```
meshes = [o.data for o in context.selected_objects if o.type == 'MESH']
```

Comment: I'm still not good at blender python, so I'm not sure how to use the source you gave me.
Are you testing on console?
When the code is confirmed after testing in a text editor, I register it as a class and make a button with the UI and use it.
I'm trying to test my code in a text editor and I'm wondering how to write it.

Comment: Thanks for Text Editor Script Examples.

The second sentence (swap object names) works fine, but it's not the function I'm trying to solve.
But I was surprised by the new features.

When I run the first sentence that seems important, I get an error, and I'm not sure which part I need to change.
I am not able to properly test the source code you gave me due to my low understanding.

Comment: Lets call all the scripts in answer 1 to 5 , in 4 "swap object names" you need all the script from script 3 above `sks  = [... `    Read question and answered re the goal of running both scripts which AFAICT is swapping object names. The shapekey names to be precise. The second part I ignored since, well I just don't think it is a two step process, or worth writing a new or editing a script should any name change.  Very flash GIF btw. Strongly recommend nutting things out in python console.  Hope I was of some assistance.

Comment: What an amazing hybrid of pythonic and non-pythonic variable swapping! I played around with it and I think I figured the oneliner: `a.name, b.name, a.name = b.name, a.name, b.name`

Comment: cool bananas. ...

Comment: It's the perfect solution for my case! Thanks a lot!