# How to see a active shape key's name?

Tags: python, scripting, objects

In the following source code, "**obj.name**" and "**obj.data.name**" work fine.

But "**obj.shape_keys.name**" doesn't work. T.T

I wonder how to fix it.

```
row = layout.row()
row.label(text="Active object is: " + obj.name)
row = layout.row()
row.label(text="Active object's data name is: " + obj.data.name)
row = layout.row()
row.label(text="Active object's shape_keys name is: " + obj.shape_keys.name)
```

[image]

Comment: To reiterate prior advice, use the python console. It will give immediate feed back on `C.object.shape_keys` That an object has no attribute "shape_keys" barely worth creating an image and asking a question over.  As mentioned in https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/237565/15543 the shapekeys belongs to the mesh not the object. `obj.data.shape_keys.name`

Comment: The active shape key's name is `obj.shape_keys_active.name`  This points to a key block of the shape keys list, eg "Basis" or "Key" etc. of  `obj.data.shape_keys` which are stored in `bpy.data.shape_keys`   Another object with same linked mesh has the same shape keys. But since the `obj.active_shape_key_index` is on the object, can have a different one active on different objects. Quesiton Title asks one thing, content another.

Comment: Thank you for your help! I understand a little bit. and with the `obj.data.shape_keys.name` you mentioned, I got the answer to the question.  Thanks and sorry for the repetitive explanation due to my lack of Python knowledge.

Comment: @batFINGER I'm just starting to learn bpy. Do you mind if I use these comments to check my understanding?  Should it be `active_shape_keys.name` rather than `shape_keys_active.name`?

Comment: @MartyFouts `obj.data.shape_keys` is all the shapekeys on a mesh.  `obj.shape_keys_active` is one keblock of that set. _eg_ if it points to `obj.data.shape_keys.key_blocks["Basis"]` then that is the active shape key.  As mentioned, the python console is a good place to see how these things work. eg type in `C.object.data.shape_keys`

Comment: The reason I asked is that if I enter `C.active_object.shape_key` on the console and try completion, it only offers `_` and not `s`, but `C.active_object.active_shape_key.name` does exist and returns the name of the active shape key, as you describe `shape_keys_active.name` doing and I was wondering how the OP's `obj` relates to `C.active_object`.

Comment: If shapekeys on a mesh come in a bag, OP wanted the name of the bag, not the active shape key that's in the bag.  The outliner shows the name of the bag, and (in my version) does not expand  the individual keys blocks within (what we see in mesh shape keys list... _ie_ the bag contents..

Answer (score 0):

`Object.active_shape_key` returns the active shape key (data-block): https://docs.blender.org/api/current/bpy.types.Object.html#bpy.types.Object.active_shape_key

```
obj = bpy.context.object
print(obj.active_shape_key)
# bpy.data.shape_keys['Key'].key_blocks["Key 1"]
```

... and as expected, `ShapeKey.name` returns the name of the shape key (string): https://docs.blender.org/api/current/bpy.types.ShapeKey.html#bpy.types.ShapeKey.name

```
sk = obj.active_shape_key
print(sk.name)
# 'Key 1'
```